# If $\boldsymbol{w}\in \mathbb{R}^M$ how can I express $\sum_{m=1}^{M}|w_m|$ in vector notation?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors, normed-spaces

Assume $\boldsymbol{w}\in \mathbb{R}^{M}$ to be a vector. How, can I express

$$l_1=\sum_{m=1}^{M}|w_m|$$ using only vector notation?

I essentially want to express the $\ell^1$ norm without introducing a new notation to my readers, who are not mathematicians.

I thought about introducing the vector $\tilde{\boldsymbol{w}}$ as the vector which has the absolute values of the coordinates of $\boldsymbol{w}$ as its coordinates and then to use the vector $\boldsymbol{1}=[1,1,\ldots,1]^T\in\mathbb{R}^M$ to write

$$l_1 = \boldsymbol{1}^T\tilde{\boldsymbol{w}}$$

but this seems quite involved.

EDIT: I also thought about introducing the vector valued component wise signum function $\textbf{sgn} (\boldsymbol{w})$ and then to use

$$l_1 = \textbf{sgn}^T (\boldsymbol{w})\boldsymbol{w}.$$

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I don't want to use $\|\boldsymbol{w}\|_1$ because I will have to define this by using the sum itself.

Comment: It's the $\ell^1$ norm: $\|\mathbf{w}\|_1$.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: And How do you define the $l^1$ norm ... by the sum that was there from the beginning? That is the reason why I do not want to use the $l^1$ norm.

Comment: The equation you wrote there is the definition of the $\ell^1$ norm. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, here. I suppose you could write it using the Einstein summation convention as $l_1=\sqrt{w_mw_m^*}$ if you don't want to write the summation symbol. But you'd have to explain to your audience that you're using that convention.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I would not consider index notation as using vector notation (see title).

Comment: What you're trying to do is still quite the mystery to me, but the notation $\|\mathbf{w}\|_1$ is the best way to go, here. It's a very widely-understood notation - you don't have to define it most of the time. Professional mathematicians generally understand what that means.

Comment: I just want to express the $l_1$ norm by using $\boldsymbol{w}$ instead of introducing a new notation to my readers, which are not mathematicians.

Comment: @Downvoter: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Yeah, I think the ideas you already have are probably the best. You really have to use the dot product (essentially - I understand you might not want to use that notation) in a clever way; you definitely can't dot $\mathbf{w}$ with itself.